# GraphDatabaseFactory not found while compiling neo4j project with maven

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I'm trying to compile a simple project that create a database with GraphDatabaseFactory with this command:

`mvn compile`

Then, I'm getting success but when trying to execute this file:

```
`
package com.milanamos;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;


public class MilanamosCmd {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final int n = 10;
        GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        GraphDatabaseService db= dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("C:/Documents"));
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ............

            long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("GENERATE "+ (t3-t2) +"ms");
            System.out.println("Done successfully");
    } 
}`
```

I got this:

```
`
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ planetoptim-neo4j ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseFactory
        at com.milanamos.MilanamosCmd.main(MilanamosCmd.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.919 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-10T19:56:10+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/609M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project planetoptim-neo4j: An exception occured while executing the Java class. org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseFactory: org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory -> `
```

Any help please.

Thank you

Comment: How are you executing the main method?   This sure looks like your neo4j dependencies aren't being included in your java $CLASSPATH.   Are you using maven, or running the jar directly ?

Comment: I'm executing my main method by using maven

Comment: *How* are you doing it by maven, and can you confirm what your class path is when you do so?

Answer (score 0):

The new neo4j version from maven repository might not present in the package structure that that you mentioned above.
I was facing the same error for version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and the error got resolved when I changed the version to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.18</version>
</dependency>
```